# What is the difference between a nullable string (string?) and a string initiated to a forgiven null (string s = null!)

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, nullable-reference-types

What is the difference between a nullable string (string?) and a string initiated to a forgiven null (string s = null!)

```
public string? nullableString {get;set;} = null;
public string forgiveString {get;set;} = null!
```

Are there any situations where you would want to use one over the other? Are they functionally equivalent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505347/non-nullable-property-must-contain-a-non-null-value-when-exiting-constructor-co/69685202#69685202

Answer (score 4):

> What is the difference between a nullable string (string?) and a string initiated to a forgiven null (string s = null!)

One is *correct*. The other is *really dumb*.

> Are there any situations where you would want to use one over the other?

In this author's opinion, no.

...but there *are* plenty of cases where `!` is needed due to current limitations of C#'s nullable reference types feature, including `Expression<>`, `ValueTuple`, Linq, but property initialization is not one of them: if a property is "never `null`" then the property *must* be assigned in the constructor or in an initializer (and since C# 11: with the `required` modifier), therefore using `= null!` to initialize a property is unnecessary and incorrect.

If you do have legacy code that cannot use nullable reference types, or code that uses some runtime sytem for intialization (such as `DbSet<T>` properties in `DbContext` in Entity Framework) then use scoped `#pragma` and `#nullable` directives to suppress warnings instead of `!` and always add an explanatory comment justifying why so that the next poor colleague of yours won't have to struggle unnecessarily to understand what's going on.

> Are they functionally equivalent?

**No**.

A class member declaration of `public string Foo { get; set; }` [is a contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914298/how-to-understand-the-meaning-of-contract) that says "`Foo` will never be `null`: it will *always* be safe to dereference the `String`-reference this property's getter returns, and it is illegal to pass a `null` reference into the property setter."

Skirting rules with  `= null!` is like saying "This property will never be `null`, unless it is. *Have fun*.". Don't do it.

---

*Another* reason not to do `= null!` with `DbContext`'s `DbSet<T>` properties is because *reference-type fields* are always initialized to `null` anyway before being populated by `DbContext`'s constructor (e.g. EF6 uses its *magical* `DbContext.DiscoverAndInitializeSets()` method), so explicitly initializing a reference-type property to `null` when it's going to be set to a non-`null` object-reference by the superclass ctor is redundant.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the null forgiveness operator until I was working through the following MongoDB C# driver tutorial and the guy was using it and it confused the hell out of me : https://youtu.be/jJK9alBkzU0?t=577

Comment: @SmashCode Without commenting on that particular video, I note that YouTube "coding" tutorials are not generally known for their quality or adherence to best-practices. (I'll make an exception for [Coding Train](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvjgXvBlbQiydffZU7m1_aw) - I wish I could be like him)

Comment: @Dai unfortunately Microsoft's own documentation promotes the `= null!;` pattern which is a shame. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types

Comment: @AluanHaddad I know - I should make a PR but `:effort:`.

Comment: You should. The pragma approach you suggest is so much better